# React dom router - RouterWithSubroute is not a Route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I try to add subroutes but keep getting error in ProtectedRoutes function: RouterWithSubroute is not a Route component. All component children of Routes must be a Route or React.fragment

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    termsAccepted,
    getPermissions,
    hasAlertReadPermissions,
    hasUsersModifyPermissions,
    hasActivityPermissions,
    hasCustomersPermissions,
    hasCustomersCTGModifyPermissions,
    getRole,
} from './authentication';

import { ReactComponent as activity_icon } from '../../images/icon-activity.svg';
import { ReactComponent as matter_icon } from '../../images/matter.svg';
import { ReactComponent as wpc_icon } from '../../images/wpc.svg';
import { ReactComponent as devices } from '../../images/icon-devices.svg';
import { ReactComponent as secure_objects } from '../../images/icon-secure-objects.svg';
import { ReactComponent as orders } from '../../images/icon-orders.svg';
import { ReactComponent as legal } from '../../images/legal.svg';
import { ReactComponent as productIcon } from '../../images/product.svg';
import { ReactComponent as company } from '../../images/company.svg';
import { ReactComponent as companySettings } from '../../images/gear.svg';
import { ReactComponent as intermediate } from '../../images/icon-intermediate-ca.svg';
import { ReactComponent as tnc } from '../../images/icon-terms-and-conditions.svg';
import { ReactComponent as alertIcon } from '../../images/icon-alerts.svg';
import { ReactComponent as appletUpdate } from '../../images/icon-applet-update.svg';
import Documentation from '../../pages/documentation';
import { matteradmin, wpcadmin } from '../../pages/users/constants';
import Footer from '../../components/footer';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
export const NotFound = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/not-found'));
export const PrivacyPolicy = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/privacy-policy'));
export const LegalPage = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/legal'));
export const Admin = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/admin'));
export const Products = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/products'));
export const ProductsDetails = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/products/product-details'));
export const ProductsDetailsProfile = React.lazy(() =>
    import('../../pages/products/product-details/features/details')
);
export const Users = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/users'));
export const Devices = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/device-group'));
export const Orders = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/orders'));
export const SecureObjects = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/secure-objects'));
export const SecureObjectsDetailsPage = React.lazy(() =>
    import('../../pages/secure-objects/secure-objects-details')
);
export const CustomerRegistartion = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/customer-registration'));
export const DeviceDetails = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/device-group/devices-details'));
export const NewDeviceGroup = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/device-group/new-device-group'));
export const CertificateDetails = React.lazy(() =>
    import('../../pages/services/certificate-details')
);
export const IntermediateCA = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/intermediate-ca'));
export const EventsAndAlerts = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/events-and-alerts'));
export const NXPAdminMatter = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/admin/matter'));
export const NXPAdminWpc = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/admin/wpc'));
export const Login = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/login'));
export const AppletUpdate = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/applet-update'));
export const AppletUpdateDetailsPage = React.lazy(() =>
    import('../../pages/applet-update/applet-update-details')
);
export const Matter = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/matter'));
export const WPC = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/wpc'));

const documentationRoute = {
    id: 'documentation',
    url: '/documentation',
    name: 'documentation',
    icon: legal,
    component: Documentation,
    routes: [],
};

export const LEGAL = [
    {
        id: 'privacyterms',
        url: '/privacy-and-terms',
        name: 'privacy_and_terms',
        icon: tnc,
        component: LegalPage,
        routes: [],
    },
];

const GENERAL_DATA_VIEW = [
    // '/audits'
    // '/service-settings/protocols',
    // '/customers/termsAndConditions.pdf',
    // '/customers/termsAndConditions.html',
    // '/products',
];

const GENERAL_DATA_MODIFY = [
    // '/user/acceptTermsAndConditions'
];

const DEVICE_GROUPS_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'device-groups',
        url: '/device-groups',
        name: 'devices',
        icon: devices,
        component: Devices,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'device-group-details',
                url: '/device-groups/:hwtype/:device12nc/:deviceGroupId/:deviceGroupName',
                component: DeviceDetails,
                routes: [],
            },
        ],
    },
];

const DEVICE_GROUPS_MODIFY = [
    {
        id: 'device-groups',
        url: '/device-groups',
        name: 'devices',
        icon: devices,
        component: Devices,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'new-device-group',
                url: '/device-groups/new-device-group',
                component: NewDeviceGroup,
                routes: [],
            },
            {
                id: 'device-group-details',
                url: '/device-groups/:hwtype/:device12nc/:deviceGroupId/:deviceGroupName',
                component: DeviceDetails,
                routes: [],
            },
        ],
    },
];

const DEVICE_GROUPS_WHITELIST = [
    {
        id: 'device-groups',
        url: '/device-groups',
        name: 'devices',
        icon: devices,
        component: Devices,
        routes: [],
    },
    // '/products/{nc12}/device-groups/{deviceGroupId}/whitelist-devices',
    // '/products/{nc12}/device-groups/{deviceGroupId}/whitelist-devices-csv',
];

const RTP_ASSIGN = [];
const RTP_CHANGE_SETTINGS = [];
const RTP_CREATE = [];
const RTP_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'secure-objects',
        url: '/secure-objects',
        name: 'secure-objects',
        icon: secure_objects,
        component: SecureObjects,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'secure-objects-details',
                url: '/secure-objects/:secureObjectId',
                component: SecureObjectsDetailsPage,
                routes: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 'intermediateCA',
        url: '/intermediate-ca',
        name: 'intermediate_ca',
        icon: intermediate,
        component: IntermediateCA,
        routes: [],
    },
    documentationRoute,
];

const KDS_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'orders',
        url: '/orders',
        name: 'orders',
        icon: orders,
        component: Orders,
        routes: [],
    },
    documentationRoute,
    // '/customers/nc12/batchId/cryptomaterials/export',
];

const KDS_DOWNLOAD = [
    {
        id: 'orders',
        url: '/orders',
        name: 'orders',
        icon: orders,
        component: Orders,
        routes: [],
    },
    // '/customers/nc12/batchId/cryptomaterials/export/{fileName}',
];

const ADMIN_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'customers',
        url: '/customers',
        name: 'customers',
        icon: company,
        component: Admin,
        routes: [],
    },
    // '/users',
];

const PRODUCT_CONFIGURATION_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'products',
        url: '/products',
        name: 'products',
        icon: productIcon,
        component: Products,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'product-details',
                url: '/products/:productQueryType/:hwtype/:productId',
                component: ProductsDetails,
                routes: [
                    {
                        id: 'product-details-profile',
                        url: '/products/:productQueryType/:hwtype/:productId/profile/:profileId',
                        component: ProductsDetailsProfile,
                        routes: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                id: 'product-details',
                url: '/products/:productQueryType/:hwtype/:productId',
                component: ProductsDetails,
                routes: [
                    {
                        id: 'product-details-profile',
                        url: '/products/bySalesItemId/:hwtype/:productId/profile/:profileId',
                        component: ProductsDetailsProfile,
                        routes: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];

const USERS_MODIFY = [
    {
        id: 'company-settings',
        url: '/company-settings',
        name: 'admin_settings',
        icon: companySettings,
        component: Users,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'create-new-user',
                url: '/company-settings/create-new-user',
                component: CustomerRegistartion,
                routes: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    // '/user/userSignup',
];

const USERS_CIG = [
    {
        id: 'company-settings',
        url: '/company-settings',
        name: 'admin_settings',
        icon: companySettings,
        component: Users,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'create-new-user',
                url: '/company-settings/create-new-user',
                component: CustomerRegistartion,
                routes: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 'documentation',
        url: '/documentation',
        name: 'documentation',
        icon: legal,
        component: Documentation,
        routes: [],
    },
];

const USERS_VIEW = [
    // '/user/userSignup',
];

const ADMIN_MODIFY = [
    {
        id: 'applet-update',
        url: '/applet-update',
        name: 'applet_update',
        icon: appletUpdate,
        component: AppletUpdate,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'applet-update-details',
                url: '/applet-update/:twelveNCId',
                component: AppletUpdateDetailsPage,
                routes: [],
            },
        ],
    },
];

const AUS_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'applet-update',
        url: '/applet-update',
        name: 'applet_update',
        icon: appletUpdate,
        component: AppletUpdate,
        routes: [
            {
                id: 'applet-update-details',
                url: '/applet-update/:twelveNCId',
                component: AppletUpdateDetailsPage,
                routes: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    documentationRoute,
];

// only for admin
const ALERTS_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'alerts',
        url: '/alerts',
        name: 'alerts',
        icon: alertIcon,
        component: EventsAndAlerts,
        routes: [],
    },
];

const ACTIVITY_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'activity',
        url: '/activity',
        name: 'activity',
        icon: activity_icon,
        component: EventsAndAlerts,
        routes: [],
    },
];

const EVENTS_AND_ALERTS_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'events-and-alerts',
        url: '/events-and-alerts',
        name: 'events_and_alerts',
        icon: activity_icon,
        component: EventsAndAlerts,
        routes: [],
    },
];
const MATTER_MANAGE_VID_PAI = [
    {
        id: 'matter',
        url: '/matter',
        name: 'matter',
        icon: matter_icon,
        component: Matter,
        routes: [],
    },
    documentationRoute,
];

const WPC_MANAGE_PUC = [
    {
        id: 'wpc',
        url: '/wpc',
        name: 'wpc',
        icon: wpc_icon,
        component: WPC,
        routes: [],
    },
    documentationRoute,
];

const WPC_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'wpc',
        url: '/wpc',
        name: 'wpc',
        icon: wpc_icon,
        component: WPC,
        routes: [],
    },
    documentationRoute,
];

const MATTER_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'matter',
        url: '/matter',
        name: 'matter',
        icon: matter_icon,
        component: Matter,
        routes: [],
    },
    documentationRoute,
];

const MATTER_ADMIN_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'matter',
        url: '/matter',
        name: 'matter',
        icon: matter_icon,
        component: NXPAdminMatter,
        routes: [],
    },
];

const WPC_ADMIN_VIEW = [
    {
        id: 'wpc',
        url: '/wpc',
        name: 'wpc',
        icon: wpc_icon,
        component: NXPAdminWpc,
        routes: [],
    },
];

const permissionsMenus = {
    GENERAL_DATA_VIEW,
    ADMIN_VIEW,
    DEVICE_GROUPS_WHITELIST,
    DEVICE_GROUPS_MODIFY,
    DEVICE_GROUPS_VIEW,
    RTP_VIEW,
    RTP_ASSIGN,
    RTP_CHANGE_SETTINGS,
    RTP_CREATE,
    KDS_DOWNLOAD,
    KDS_VIEW,
    GENERAL_DATA_MODIFY,
    USERS_VIEW,
    ADMIN_MODIFY,
    AUS_VIEW,
    MATTER_MANAGE_VID_PAI,
    MATTER_VIEW,
    WPC_MANAGE_PUC,
    WPC_VIEW,
    // RTP_SYSTEM_PROFILE_VIEW,
    PRODUCT_CONFIGURATION_VIEW,
    MATTER_ADMIN_VIEW,
    WPC_ADMIN_VIEW,
    // USER_MODIFY <- this does not belong in the main menu
};

// save current routes so there is no need to calculate route on every render
let currentRoutes = [];

/**
 * Adds additional routes to the user for a different section on the navigation side menu
 * @todo we can remove this function and use the checkIfShowSeparator in the sidebar component instead of separate menu items,
 *              this will also reduce the complexity of adding/removing/moving routes
 */
export const routesPerUser = termsAccepted => {
    let listOfRoutes = [...LEGAL];

    if (!termsAccepted) {
        return listOfRoutes;
    }

    const hasUserModify = hasUsersModifyPermissions();
    const hasAlertRead = hasAlertReadPermissions();
    const hasActivity = hasActivityPermissions();
    const hasCustomersRead = hasCustomersPermissions();
    const hasCIGPermissions = hasCustomersCTGModifyPermissions();

    if (!hasCustomersRead && hasUserModify) {
        listOfRoutes = [...listOfRoutes, ...USERS_MODIFY];
    }
    if (!hasCustomersRead && hasCIGPermissions) {
        listOfRoutes = [...listOfRoutes, ...USERS_CIG];
    }

    if (hasAlertRead && !hasActivity) {
        listOfRoutes = [...listOfRoutes, ...ALERTS_VIEW];
    } else if (!hasAlertRead && hasActivity && !hasCIGPermissions) {
        listOfRoutes = [...listOfRoutes, ...ACTIVITY_VIEW];
    } else if (hasAlertRead && hasActivity) {
        listOfRoutes = [...listOfRoutes, ...EVENTS_AND_ALERTS_VIEW];
    }

    return listOfRoutes.map(item => ({ ...item, isMain: true }));
};

/**
 * Cross check permissions per role and permissions of the current user
 */
export const routesPerRole = permissionsUpToDate => {
    if (!termsAccepted()) {
        return [];
    }
    const permissions = getPermissions();
    if (!permissions) {
        return [];
    }
    const routes = [];

    // immediately return routes if permissions are up to date
    if (permissionsUpToDate && currentRoutes.length > 0) {
        return currentRoutes;
    }

    // iterate over all the available permissions
    for (const menuName in permissionsMenus) {
        // iterate over all the user assigned permissions
        for (const permission of permissions) {
            // check if assigned permission matches any available permission
            if (permission === menuName) {
                // iterate over all the routes in an available permission (permissionsMenu)
                for (const menu of permissionsMenus[menuName]) {
                    // check if route already exists
                    const index = routes.findIndex(existingRoute => existingRoute.id === menu.id);
                    // index > -1 means that the route already exists in the routes array
                    if (index > -1) {
                        const routesToAdd = [];
                        // go through all level 2 sub-routes
                        for (const menuRoute of menu.routes) {
                            // check if sub-route already exists on the route
                            const routesIndex = routes[index].routes.findIndex(
                                existingRoute => existingRoute.id === menuRoute.id
                            );
                            // if the sub-routes doesn't exists already, add it to routesToAdd
                            if (routesIndex < 0) {
                                routesToAdd.push(menuRoute);
                            }
                        }
                        // add sub-routes to already existing route
                        routes[index].routes = [...routes[index].routes, ...routesToAdd];
                    } else {
                        routes.push(menu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    currentRoutes = routes.map(item => ({ ...item, isMain: true }));
    return currentRoutes;
};

/**
 * Renders sub-routes of a route
 */
export const RouteWithSubroute = ({id, url, component: Component, routes}) => {
    console.log("Rendering RouteWithSubroute");
    return (
        <Route
            data-route={url}
            key={id}
            path={`${url}`}
            element={props => (
                    <Component {...props} routes={routes} />
            )}
        />
    );
};
export const ProtectedRoutes = (location, permissionsUpToDate) => {
    console.log("Rendering ProtectedRoutes")
    const tocAccepted = termsAccepted();
    const routes = routesPerRole(permissionsUpToDate);
    const userRoutes = routesPerUser(tocAccepted);
    let home = '';
    let alwaysRedirectToTNCifPageNotFound = false;
    console.log(routes)

    if (tocAccepted) {
        if (location.pathname === '/') {
            if (hasCustomersPermissions()) {
                home = '/customers';
            } else if (hasCustomersCTGModifyPermissions()) {
                home = '/company-settings';
            } else if (getRole() === matteradmin) {
                home = '/matter';
            } else if (getRole() === wpcadmin) {
                home = '/wpc';
            } else {
                home = '/documentation';
            }
        }
    } else {
        home = '/privacy-and-terms';
        alwaysRedirectToTNCifPageNotFound = true;
    }
    console.log(location, tocAccepted)
    return (
        <Routes key={location.key} location={location}>
            {tocAccepted && routes.length && routes.map(route => (
                <RouteWithSubroute key={route.id} {...route} />
            ))}
            {userRoutes.map(route => (
                <RouteWithSubroute key={route.id} {...route} />
            ))}
            {!alwaysRedirectToTNCifPageNotFound && <Navigate to={home} />}
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};

/**
 * Renders the routes where login is not needed
 */
export const UnprotectedRoutes = (location) => {
    const tocAccepted = termsAccepted();

    if (tocAccepted == null) {
        currentRoutes = [];
    }

    return (
        <Routes key={location.key} location={location}>
            <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

It does not even get inside the RouteWithSubroute, because console log does not getting displayed. Dont know what else to try

Comment: Please provide MINIMAL reproducible example, there is way too much code to analyse